# Show that the solutions of Euler-Lagrange equation are in form of $(x^2-y^2)\cos(\alpha) +2xy\sin(\alpha) = d$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, euler-lagrange-equation

I have to how that the solutions of Euler-Lagrange equation $$I(y)=\int_a^b\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\sqrt{1+y'^2}dx$$
are in form of $(x^2-y^2)\cos(\alpha) +2xy\sin(\alpha) = d$, where $\alpha, d \in \mathbb{R}$ and
I don't really now where to start. How would I go about this question?